# How do I pass a variable as a parameter in Fortran

Tags: fortran, implementation

Let be a function with many input arguments like: `F = F(x,y,a,b)`.

In Python, it is possible to pass some arguments as variables while other arguments as parameters like: `F = F(x,y,a,b, (args=x,a))`.

How can I do it in Fortran?

Comment: Rather than asking how to mimic Python (which I for one don't understand), can you say what you are trying to get the Fortran to do?

Comment: I do know some Python, but I do not know this syntax. Please explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: And remember that Fortran variables are different from Python variables. Fortran uses values, Python references. These two languages are different.  You have to explain what you want to achieve **in Fortran**, not just what the Python syntax means.

Comment: @VladimirF "Fortran uses values" ?

Comment: @albert In the sense that after `integer :: i` `i` is really a place in memory that gets overwritten with a different value if you do `i = 5`. In Python a variable is a reference and `i = 5` means creating a reference named `i` to some constant value in memory that has value 5. If you then do `i = 6` then `i` will point somewhere else to some other constant value.

Comment: @VladimirF This is clear to me, but to people not used to it it might be a bit different as it is taught "Fortran passes arguments by reference" ,

Comment: I did not invent the notion http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/val-vs-ref-semantics.html

Comment: Also Fortran is not required to pass arguments by reference, and to assume it does can lead to incorrect code